# Ionic loader: $ionicLoading.show() issue, loader not getting called on first time

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am having this weird problem with $ionicLoading directive. I am trying to show loader on every state change.

```
.run(['$rootScope','$ionicLoading', function ($rootScope, $ionicLoading){
  $rootScope.$on('loading:show', function () {
    $rootScope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner>',
        delay: 1
    }).then(function(){
      console.log('showing loader');
    }, function(error){
      console.log('something is breaking');
    });
  });
  $rootScope.$on('loading:hide', function () {
   $ionicLoading.hide();
  });
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function () {
    console.log('please wait...');
    $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');
 });

 $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
   console.log('done');
   $rootScope.$broadcast('loading:hide');
  });
}]);
```

On page load or on stateChangeStart, $ionicLoading.show() is getting called but it is returning promise as error (error: cancelled, something is breaking is getting printed) & hence Loader is not showing.
**Now** if I call the `$rootScope.$broadcast('loading:show');` event on `$stateChangeSuccess`, after the hide event, then loader is showing. (I got to know this by just playing around).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    $ionicLoading.show();
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    console.error(error);
    $ionicLoading.hide();
});
```

Comment: I don't its different from what I did. Anyway its not working too. $ionicLoading.show(); returns promise as error.

Comment: What promise does it return as error? It should be indeed no different from what you did, just simpler and I've already used and tested it.